# How to update the displayed content of a file on an HTML page with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I'm trying to continuously display the contents of a file on my HTML page
(at every 'X' times). In other words, I want to make a logger and visualize it as if it were in a terminal. I'm new to AJAX and I'm not exactly sure how to set up the ajax call in the javascript, more specifically, what URL goes by parameter.

I'm passing a model through my controller to a form in thymeleaf:

```
 <form id="formTest" class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{'log/'}" th:object="${log}" method="post">
      ...
</form>
```

This way I can create an object and then print its contents. The contents of the object originate from a file*.log*, which is located in a remote directory.

```
 <p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
```

The file path is mapped in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logContent_post(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
            try {    
                fileNumberLines(log);
                                     // lineOccurrence, firstLine,  lastLine,  logPath
                log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.setContent(
                    getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        }

        model.put("path", logsDir);
        model.put("log", log);
        model.put("currentPage", "logs");
        model.put("root", root);

        return "log";
    }
```

My Ajax function

```
function att(){
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '',
        cache: false,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("Content:" +  data);
        },
        complete : function() {

        }
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    if (window.location.pathname == '/log/') {
        att();
    }
}, 5000);
```

I've tried to pass several "url's" through AJAX, but either I get 404 () or null as a return. So **my question:** What Url should I pass by parameter?

Comment: the action of form doesn't execute when you use ajax calls, you should put it in the ajax  url : '??'   
404 may be from another error in the server side, try it alone then integrate it with your page